# New line after each answer

Tags: python

I would like to enquire how do i make after each ans, my qns will start at a new line.

```
def gfunction(p):
    ql=[]
    for sList in p:
        if(len(subList)>1):
            q=""
            q+=str(sList[0])
            a=sList[0]
            for i in range(1,len(sList)):
                q+=" X "+str(sList[i])
                a*=sList[i]
                sDic={'q':q,'a':a}
                ql.append(sDic)
    return ql
```

Comment: `{'qns': '1 x 2 x 3 x 5', 'ans': 50 }` not `30`?

Comment: If you want to print each on its own line, try `for x in generatefunction(lst): print(x)`

Comment: yes, thanks!  yep it was a typo.

Comment: BTW, for Python 3.8 you can just use `[{"qns": ' x '.join(map(str, x)), "ans": math.prod(x)} for x in lst]`, and for older versions `functools.reduce(operator.mul, x)` instead of `math.prod`

Answer (score 0):

I would just iterate over it and print each line.

```
def generatefunction(p):
    questionList=[]
    for subList in p:
        if(len(subList)>2):
            question=""
            question+=str(subList[0])
            ans=subList[0]
            for i in range(1,len(subList)):
                question+=" x "+str(subList[i])
                ans*=subList[i]
                subDict={'qns':question,'ans':ans}
                questionList.append(subDict)
    return questionList

lst=[[1,2,2],[2,5,5],[3,4],[0,2],[1,2,3,5],[1]]

newList= generatefunction(lst)
for x in newList:
  print(x)
```

If I understood this correctly, this is what you are looking for correct?

Comment: Yes tobias_k had answered my qn too. thanks too! However i'm still getting [{'qns': '1 x 2, 'ans': 4} instead of  [{'qns': '1 x 2 x 2', 'ans': 4}

Answer (score 0):

```
def generatefunction(p):
    questionList=[]
    
    for subList in p:
        ans = 1
        if(len(subList)>2):
            question = ""
            for element in subList:
                if len(question)==0:
                    question = f"{element}"
                else:
                    question = f"{question} x {element}"
                ans *=element
            subDict={'qns':question,'ans':ans}
            questionList.append(subDict)
    return questionList

lst=[[1,2,2],[2,5,5],[3,4],[0,2],[1,2,3,5],[1]]

#Print each element of list in new line
for i in generatefunction(lst):    print(i)
```